# Get child element programmatically selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What I am trying to achieve is to programmatically open the first video on the web page which is enabled and displayed. I am getting the video elements by using Xpath search method and clicking on the first one available. What I want to achieve is to open that divider(video element) and inside of it search for another divider but specifically that one inside of the divider I already clicked on.

This is how I am trying to do it now:

```
 public void ClickOnTheProperty()
    {
        var isClicked = false;

        var properties = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-md-3 col-sm-3')]"));
        for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
        {
            if (properties[i].Enabled && properties[i].Displayed)
            {
                var smallContainer =
                    properties[i].FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'miniature lightingshow')]"));
                for (var j = 0; j < smallContainer.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (smallContainer[j].Displayed && smallContainer[j].Enabled)
                    {
                        var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver;
                        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", smallContainer[i]);
                        isClicked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!isClicked)
        {
            throw new Exception("No property found");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? If you cannot understand what my problem is , or I did not explain very well, I will try to answer all the questions you need additionally.

Comment: What is the problem? You've shown code great, now tell us what doesn't work with it.

Comment: @Arran I have 33 dividers containing class (col-md-3 col-sm-3) in each of these I have only one class (miniature lightingshow), but somehow instead of getting that one specific element inside of the divider I am getting some other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that XPath (not Selenium) requires a little more of a 'push' to tell it about scopes.

Your solution is to change your second XPath from:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'miniature lightingshow')]"
```

to:

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'miniature lightingshow')]"
```

The `.` telling XPath 'search within my current parent'.

Comment: It sounds as a logical explanation , once I saw you answer I though that's the solution but now I am getting an no such element exception.

Comment: Test the whole thing together then as one long XPath: `//div[contains(@class, 'col-md-3 col-sm-3')]/.//div[contains(@class, 'miniature lightingshow')]`...does it work? If no, your XPath is actually structurally wrong (we'll need to see the HTML itself to help with that).

Comment: I solved my problem , there was several little but important things. Thank you for help , your answer helped me because I didn't know about dot .//div .

Comment: M.G. - can i suggest that you express the solution that you arrived at, just in case someone stumbles upon this with a similar issue, only to be frustrated at not having closure - cheers